# Htaccess - If parameter does not equal specific words, then redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I have a page that loads video tutorials.  The address looks like: www.mydomain.com/tutorials.html

The videos are organized in to categories and subcategories, and when a category/subcategory is selected, I'm using the following Htaccess code to change the URL:

```
RewriteRule tutorials/(.*) tutorials.html?cat=$1?subcat=$2
```

This gives me a nice, clean URL that looks like: www.mydomain.com/tutorials/category1/subcategory1

The downside, though, is that a user could manually type in www.mydomain.com/tutorials/foo/bar, and while they wouldn't get any results, the page would still load.

I would like to limit the cat and subcat parameters to specific pre-defined words, so that if someone manually types in a category that doesn't exist, they will get redirected to the home page.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you handle this in your `tutorials` script?

Comment: I agree - this would make the most sense.  However, unfortunately, I'm working within the confines of an e-commerce store. The store allows me to call my own custom php scripts, but I cannot perform php header redirects.

Comment: Sounds strange. Anyway you might look into RewriteMap for this.